# RxJava2: scan with hot source - always one value behind?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I am having trouble understanding the behavior of `scan` in combination with a hot source - I was first experiencing this in a production setting but I was thankfully able to reproduce the effect in a toy example.

Here we go:

```
    PublishRelay<Integer> source = PublishRelay.create();

    Flowable<Integer> sink = source.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
            .scan(1, new BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer apply(Integer integer, Integer integer2) throws Exception {
                    int result = integer + integer2;
                    System.out.println(String.format("%d + %d = %d", integer, integer2, result));
                    return result;
                }
            })
            .share();

    Thread.sleep(2_000);
    System.out.println(String.format("sending: %d", 2));
    source.accept(2);

    System.out.println(String.format("subscribing now"));
    sink.subscribe(
            new Consumer<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Integer integer) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println(String.format("onNext: %d", integer));
                }
            }
    );
    System.out.println(String.format("subscribing done"));

    Thread.sleep(2_000);
    System.out.println(String.format("sending: %d", 3));
    source.accept(3);

    Thread.sleep(2_000);
    System.out.println(String.format("sending: %d", 4));
    source.accept(4);

    Thread.sleep(2_000);
    System.out.println(String.format("done"));
```

The output of this code is:

```
sending: 2
subscribing now
subscribing done
sending: 3
1 + 3 = 4
onNext: 1
sending: 4
4 + 4 = 8
onNext: 4
done
```

Now, my question is: Why it always one value behind? Why is not:

```
sending: 2
subscribing now
subscribing done
sending: 3
1 + 3 = 4
onNext: *4*
sending: 4
4 + 4 = 8
onNext: *8*
done
```

And, what can I do about that? Do I need to make sure that the source will only emit new items *after* the `scan` itself has at least one subscriber?

Comment: First of all, upgrade to RxJava 2.1.1 or later and check again.

Comment: Oh, damn - I'd thought I already was on 2.1.1, but that was in a library I didn't use for the test. And the main project was still at 2.0.5... Sorry and thanks a lot!